# Make a table from JSON data in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

i am looking to make something like this:

[Table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXtv5.png)

Let's say that i have two arrays:

```
names: ["Prisma 2 Case", "PP-Bizon", ...]
imgs: ["img1.png", "img2.png", ...]
```

one with names and one with picture of the item. What i want to make is a table that has an image and the name in one cell.

I hav etried something like this:

```
<table className="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      {this.state.names.map((data, i) => {
        return <th key={i}>{data}</th>;
      })}
    </tr>
    <tr>
      {this.state.imgs.map((data, i) => {
        return (
          <td key={i}>
            <img className="style" src={data} alt="" />
          </td>
        );
      })}
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>;
```

But what it did are two seperate rows. It has to by some loop because the number of owned items isnt always the same.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: The json data you have is there a way you could fix it let's say something like this 
`[{name: "Prisma 2 Case" image: "img1.png"}, {name: "PP-Bizon" image: "img2.png"}, ...]`

Comment: if array are equal in size ... use `i` index to render imeges while mapping names ... `names.map(name,i){ {render name} ... {render img using imgs[i] } }`

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way to solve this problem is create one array and each object of this array has a object that consist of name and image field.
then use map and show this new array.

arr = [{name:'',image:''}]

Answer (score 1):

You will need only one loop to achieve what you're looking for.
Depending on what you're trying to do and your style, you may need to wrap the name with a span.

Note that this will only work if your two arrays have the same length and are sorted equally (i.e first image is for the first name, and so on).

```js
<table className="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      {this.state.names.map((data, i) => {
        return (
          <td key={i}>
            <img className="style" src={this.state.imgs[i]} alt="" />
            {data}
          </td>
        );
      })}
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need for the project you are doing hope it helps, tip tho its better to make your json data into something like this `[{name: "Prisma 2 Case" image: "img1.png"}, {name: "PP-Bizon" image: "img2.png"}, ...]`

Please let me know if something went wrong here.

```
import React from "react";

function Sample() {
  const data = [
    {
      names: ["Prisma 2 Case", "PP-Bizon"],
      imgs: ["img1.png", "img2.png"],
    },
  ];

  return (
    <>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Color</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {data.map(({ names, imgs }) => {
            return names.map((name, index) => (
              <tr key={name}>
                <td key={name}>{name}</td>
                <td key={name}>{imgs[index]}</td>
              </tr>
            ));
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </>
  );
}

export default Sample;
```